# Java find matching chronological order between two users data

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have user session captured for click on certain uri and need to find out matching maximum click of chronological order. for example:

```
User1 = {"/blue", "/green", "/pink", "/orange", "/white", "/gray"} 

User2 = {"/brown", "/green", "/pink", "/orange", "/red", "/gray"}

User3 = {"/blue", "/green", "/pink"}

User4 = {"/blue"}
```

I need a method which will take two parameter and should return the matching maximum click e.g.

Scenario 1-

```java
public static void findMaxHitClick( String User1, String User2) {

    # output should be {"/green", "/pink", "/orange"}
}
```

Scenario 2-

```java
public static void findMaxHitClick( String User3, String User4) {

    # output should be {"/blue"}
}
```

What is efficient way to achieve above in java?

Comment: How the common output for `{"/blue", "/green", "/pink"}` and `{"/blue"}` is expected to be `/red`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko, sorry for misunderstanding , i updated the question and it to find the chronological order

Comment: @AlexRudenko , in my post i added ```user3``` and ```user4``` should return ```/blue``` ..

Answer (score 1):

First, the inputs as well as the output of `findMaxHitClick` (which cannot be declared as `void`) should be arrays or collections of String.

Next, there is method `Collections::retainAll` which allows to find an intersection of two collections.

Thus, `findMaxHitClick` may be implemented like this:

```java
public static Collection<String> findMaxHitClick(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    Set<String> s1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
    Set<String> s2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
    
    s1.retainAll(s2);
    
    return s1;
}
```

Tests:

```java
String[] User1 = {"/blue", "/green", "/pink", "/orange", "/white", "/gray"};
String[] User2 = {"/brown", "/green", "/pink", "/orange", "/red", "/gray"};
String[] User3 = {"/blue", "/green", "/pink"};
String[] User4 = {"/blue"};

System.out.println(findMaxHitClick(User1, User2));
System.out.println(findMaxHitClick(User3, User4));
```

Output:

```
[/green, /pink, /orange, /gray]  // /gray occurs in both User1 & User2
[/blue]                          // User3 & User4 have common /blue, not /red
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was to find the matching chronological order so first output should be {"/green", "/pink", "/orange"}

Comment: What do you mean by _chronological order_?  If the insertion order matters, `LinkedHashSet` may be used instead, check the update.  Also, `/gray` is common to  User1 and User2